# VideoJS volume control handle second player

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I'm working on multi-language project with using JS Video player. I would like to ask whether it is possible to link the volume control event from first video player to another player on the site. So when a change occurs  of volume in the first player will be an same change transfered to the second player.
Thanks for your response.
Best regards
JS

Comment: Are you trying to have two players with the same volume or have one player muted, but its volume control control another player?

Comment: I need to hear only one sound track at one time. By default, I want to control the volume level of main video player. When user switch audio track I need to control volume level of slave audio player (while the main video player is muted).
I tried to connect the players using 'volumechange' event on main video player, volume control is connected, but I still hear audio tracks from both players.

videojs("example_video_1").on('volumechange', function(){
if(this.muted()){
videojs("example_audio_1").volume(0);
}
else{
videojs("example_audio_1").volume(this.volume());
}});

Answer (score 1):

```
const player1 = videojs('video1'), player2 = videojs('videojs2');
player1.on('volumechange', () => {
    player2.volume(player1.volume())
})
```

[volume method to get and set volume](https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Methodsvolume)

[volumechange event](https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Eventsvolumechange)

Answer (score 0):

There's work currently in progress within video.js to support audio language tracks which would better suit this use case, but a hack for now would be to move the second player's volume control into the first player

```
var player1 = videojs('video1');
var player2 = videojs('video2');
var p1vol = player1.controlBar.volumeMenuButton;
var p2vol = player2.controlBar.volumeMenuButton;
player1.muted(true);
// Insert player2's volume control before player1's control in player1's control bar
player1.controlBar.addChild(p2vol, {}, player1.controlBar.children().indexOf(p1vol));
// Remove player1's volume control
player1.controlBar.removeChild(p1vol);
```